# Create UIWebView programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I've been trying this for a while, but I'm not getting it right.

I have written the following init function in a supporting file:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024,768)];
 }
    return self;
}
```

and following in ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   UIWebView *view = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
   NSString *url=@"http://www.google.com";
   NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
   NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
   [view loadRequest:nsrequest]; 
}
```

I also tried creating the webview in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method of appDelegate, but it also didn't work.

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 36):

I hope this solution will help you.

1. As per your problem, **simply add these lines in `- (void)viewDidLoad`**

> ```
> UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
> NSString *urlString = @"https://www.google.com";
> NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
> NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
> webView loadRequest:request];
> [self.view addSubview:webView];
> ```
>
> I have used the static frame of the webView, you can use according to your requirement.

2. But `UIWebView` is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 - No longer supported; please adopt `WKWebView`, so updated code for Objective C and Swift are below

**Swift:**

```
import WebKit

let theConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: theConfiguration)
let nsurl = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
var nsrequest: URLRequest? = nil
if let nsurl = nsurl {
    nsrequest = URLRequest(url: nsurl)
}
if let nsrequest = nsrequest {
    webView.load(nsrequest)
}
view.addSubview(webView)
```

**Objective C:**

```
#import <WebKit/WKWebView.h>
#import <WebKit/WKWebViewConfiguration.h>

WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: I used static frame of web view, you can use according your requirement.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have forgotten to add `webview` as a subview of its parent view:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024,768)];
        [self addSubview:webview];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Also `viewDidLoad` is not the right place to create subviews. You should expose `webview` as a property of your view, and then access it from `viewDidLoad`, like this:

```
NSString *url=@"http://www.google.com";
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[[self.view webview] loadRequest:nsrequest];
```

Comment: @user1153798 if the code is in `UIViewController`, `self.view` should be fine. The `.view` may be wrong - try `[self.view webview]` instead (see the edit).

Answer (score 0):

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
webView.delegate = self;   
NSString *url=@"http://www.google.com";
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[webview loadRequest:nsrequest]; 
[self.view addSubview:webview];
```

Declare UIWebviewDelegate in the interface of the viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

This is answer is slight improvement over @Ashvin Ajadiya's answer. To dynamically set the width and height of the web view according to your device
use this code inside **viewWillAppear** or else it won't get proper device width and height

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    NSString *url=@"http://www.google.com";
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];
    [self.view addSubview:webview];
}
```